# How create a custom views contextual filter?

Tags: views, flags, plugins

I've a site using Drupal 10.1.x.

I need to implement the following requisites:

1. Let the users choose their "most liked" nodes (bundle `product`).
   This bundle has a entity reference field to another node bundle `company`, `field_company`, and a entity reference field to a taxonomy vocabulary.
2. Display two views: on one show all the nodes excluding all the "liked" of a specific `company`, on the other show only the "liked" nodes of a specific `company`.
   Those two view are displayed on the taxonomy term via TVI. The taxonomy term has a entity reference field to the same bundle `company` which represents the value for the above filter.

So far, I've create a flag of module *Flag*, `promoted_products` with a field, `field_company`.

The flag field is correctly filled with the `nid` of the `company` referenced in the relative field of the flagged entity with a custom event subscriber.

I've also configured the first view to display on the taxonomy term, it is a copy of the default view `taxonomy_term`.

In addition, it has a relationship with Flags - "Include only flagged content" is not active for the first view (exclude flagged nodes of company x) and active for the second one (show only flagged nodes of company x).

[image]

Now, the problem I'm facing is how to filter only for the value for the `company` (or negate that)

The idea that came to me is a custom contextual filter to which I pass the default value "Taxonomy term ID from URL" and then add to the query a condition which in pseudo-sql would be

```
SELECT * from flagging__field_company fc
 JOIN taxonomy_term__field_company tc ON tc.field_company_target_id = fc.field_company_target_id
AND tc.entity_id = {contextual_filter_value}
```

but alas I've found little documentation on how implement that.

What I fail to understand is especially how the mapper between Views and the SQL syntax works.
My code so far breaks the view with a "SQL syntax error".

And by the way, is there any good documentation\tutorial available on this topic? I couldn't find any.

This is the code of the filter so far. I've taken as example [this](https://github.com/evolvingweb/custom_views_argument). I've start to try the query syntax looking at [this](https://www.axelerant.com/blog/creating-a-custom-exposed-view-filter-in-drupal-8-to-use-with-workflow-states).

`my_module.module`:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function my_module_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['flagging']['my_module_promoted_products'] = [
    'title' => t('my_module Promoted products'),
    'real field' => 'flag_id',
    'argument' => [
      'field' => 'flag_id',
      'title' => t('my_module Promoted products'),
      'id' => 'my_module_promoted_products_filter',
    ],
  ];
}
```

The plugin:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\argument;

use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument\ManyToOne;
use Drupal\views\Views;

/**
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsArgument("my_module_promoted_products_filter")
 */
class MyModulePromotedProductsFlaggingFilter extends ManyToOne {
  public function query($group_by = FALSE) {
    if (!empty($this->value)) {
      //todo what actually write here?
$configuration = [
        'table' => 'flagging_field_company',
        'field' => 'entity_id',
        'left_table' => 'flagging',
        'left_field' => 'id',
        'operator' => '=',
      ];
      $join = Views::pluginManager('join')
        ->createInstance('standard', $configuration);
      $this->query->addRelationship('flagging_field_company', $join, 'flagging');
      $this->query->addWhere('AND', 'flagging_field_company.field_company_target_id', $this->value, 'IN');
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks.